# Removing structure of empty folders

Tags: swift, macos, recursion

I am trying to delete any empty folders in a directory (sometimes folders within folders).

Here's how I'm trying to do it (see below), however it still leaves the last folder.

If there is a better way to approach this?

---

```
func removeEmptyFoldersAt(url: URL) {
    let folderContents = try? fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.isDirectoryKey], options: [.skipsPackageDescendants, .skipsHiddenFiles]).filter({u in
        let attr = try? u.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey])
        return attr!.isDirectory!
    })
    for folder in folderContents! {
        let attr = try? folder.resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey])
        let contents = try? fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: [], options: [.skipsHiddenFiles,.skipsPackageDescendants])
        if attr!.isDirectory! && contents!.count > 0 {
            removeEmptyFoldersAt(url: folder)
        }
        if attr!.isDirectory! && contents?.count == 0 {
            try? fm.removeItem(at: folder)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like a homework problem. You should be using a Depth-First Search and deleting any empty folders you encounter: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Depth-First%20Search

Comment: All this usage of `try?` is really improper. Handle your errors.

Comment: @Alexander, point taken. You're absolutely right, of course. (I usually do catch {} everything... I just whipped this out to to test the recursion).

Answer (score 1):

I'd follow a slightly different workflow, I'd have the `removeEmptyFoldersAt` be more generic in its workflow.

So you can pass it `URL` and if:

- it's a directory, list the contents and recursively call itself with each item
- it's a file, just remove it

For example...

```
extension URL {
    var isDirectory: Bool {
       return (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.isDirectoryKey]))?.isDirectory ?? false
    }
}

func removeItem(at url: URL) throws {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    if url.isDirectory {
        for item in try fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: []) {
            try removeItem(at: item)
        }
    }
    try fm.removeItem(at: url)
}
```

*nb: I've not tested this, but this is a common workflow I've used in the past*